# javascript string split negative

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to use string split in javascript to get the last element in the array that is produced.

For example, im sure in php you can do the same and use a negative limit value to get the last item i.e. -1 or the last two items -2 etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on the result array you get from [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur".split(/ /).slice(-2) // returns ["amet", "consectetur"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a [*pop()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/pop) method that removes and returns the last element of an array:

```
"/path/to/somefile.jpg".split("/").pop();
// -> "somefile.jpg"
```

As Gumbo mentioned, [*slice()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will allow you to select a range of array elements.

Answer (score 0):

pop and splice are what you are after

```
var a = "1,2,3,4,5";
var b = a.split(/,/g).pop();
var a1 = a.split(/,/g);
var c = a1.splice(a1.length-2,a1.length);
var d = a.split(/,/g).splice(-2);
```